# How to create and save a model with multiselect values in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a model where I can assign multiple days of the week to a Customer through a form. However, when I try to save it I get the following error.

```
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(2)
```

I am using the django-multiselectfield package to create multiple select checkboxes.

https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/

model.py

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK_CHOICES = [

('Mo', 'Monday'),
('Tu', 'Tuesday'),
('We', 'Wednesday'),
('Th', 'Thursday'),
('Fr', 'Friday'),
('Sa', 'Saturday'), 
('Su', 'Sunday'), 
]

class Customer(models.Model):
    days_of_the_week = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
RECURRINGDAYS = [
        ('Mo','Monday'),
        ('Tu','Tuesday'),
        ('We','Wednesday'),
        ('Th','Thursday'),
        ('Fr','Friday'),
        ('Sa','Saturday'),
        ('Su','Sunday')
        ]

class CustomerCreateForm(forms.Form):
    days_of_the_week = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, choices=RECURRINGDAYS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label="Recurring Day(s)?")
```

views.py

```
from .models import Customer
from .forms import CustomerCreateForm
def create_customer(request):
    form = CustomerCreateForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
           recurringDays = form.cleaned_data['days_of_the_week']

           newCustomer = Customer(
                        days_of_the_week = recurringDays
                        )
           newCustomer.save()

return render(request, "customer.html", context)
```

If someone fills out the form and selects Monday and Tuesday, how do I save that to the database Customer model?

Comment: Please check database field size.

Comment: @mahdimarjanimoghadam if I set the max length to a large number it still does not save. I think I need to iterate through the days or something?

Answer (score 0):

This code works, I just spent a few hours to discover I forgot to makemigrations.

Whoops.